# Is it possible to change SAML IdentityProvider options outside of Startup.cs using Sustainsys.Saml2?

Tags: asp.net-core, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

Is it possible to set IdentityProvider options (EntityId, MetadataLocation) for Saml2 outside the Startup.cs class in an ASP.NET Core application using the Sustainsys.Saml2 library?

In my scenario, different customers will require different settings, so I will need to change the settings at runtime rather than application start.

Comment: Do you want to change `Saml2Options.SPOptions.EntityId` or `IdentityProviders` to add new `IdentityProvider`? For `Saml2Options`, you could access it by `IOptions<Saml2Options> options`, but for `Saml2Options.SPOptions.EntityId`, it will not be able to edit if you have set `saml2PSecurityTokenHandler`.

Comment: I'm looking to change the options rather than add a new provider. How can I access IOptions<Saml2Options>. Can in be injected into a controller for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can both change the settings of the `IdentityProvider` object as well as add new or remove old Idps from the `IdentityProvider` dictionary. Don't change the EntityId though as that is used as the key in the dictionary. Remove/add new instead.

There are also notifications you can use to entirely bypass the built in list of Idps and instead use your own store or create Idp objects on-the-fly.

If you use Metadata loading you should really cache them, as creating one with Metadata loading requires an outbound roundtrip to download metadata before it can be used.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm not clear how I can access the IdentityProvider dictionary outside of startup. Could you provide an example?

Comment: You need to keep a reference to it around - such as assign it to a static variable. But please note that getting a working solution for this that handle multiple users signing in at the same time for different customers is non-trivial. Mail me if you need hands-on help (commercial basis).

Answer (score 1):

This kind of expounds on the answer from Anders with some implementation details that I determined by looking at the code repository https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2 and this helpful project that shows how to add a custom scheme at runtime from a controller: https://github.com/aspnet/AuthSamples/blob/master/samples/DynamicSchemes/Controllers/AuthController.cs.

High level:

- register a few services in startup that would otherwise get registered in the `AddSaml2` function
- have a controller that allows adding the scheme with injected `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider`, SAML options `IOptionsMonitorCache<Saml2Options>`, and a default logger and cookie manager with `IPostConfigureOptions<Saml2Options>`
- use a `HostedService` that runs after startup to register existing ones from your db

Startup services

```
services.AddSingleton<IOptionsMonitorCache<Saml2Options>, OptionsCache<Saml2Options>>();

// from `Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2\Saml2AuthExtensions.cs.AddSaml2`
// register the saml services that we'll need to be able to add auth schemes at runtime
services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<Saml2Options>, PostConfigureSaml2Options>());
services.AddTransient<Saml2Handler>();
```

Methods that can be called from a controller accordingly that can add and remove SAML schemes at runtime:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Sustainsys.Saml2;
using Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2;
using Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata;

public class SsoService {
  private readonly IOptions<CoreSettings> _coreSettings;
  private readonly IAuthenticationSchemeProvider _schemeProvider;
  private readonly IPostConfigureOptions<Saml2Options> _samlPostConfigureOptions;
  private readonly IOptionsMonitorCache<Saml2Options> _optionsCache;
  private readonly SsoRepository _ssoRepository;

  public SsoService(
    IOptions<CoreSettings> coreSettings,
    IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider,
    IPostConfigureOptions<Saml2Options> samlPostConfigureOptions,
    IOptionsMonitorCache<Saml2Options> optionsCache,
    SsoRepository ssoRepository
  ) {
    _coreSettings = coreSettings;
    _schemeProvider = schemeProvider;
    _samlPostConfigureOptions = samlPostConfigureOptions;
    _optionsCache = optionsCache;
    _ssoRepository = ssoRepository;
  }

  public async Task Remove(string schemeName) {
    _schemeProvider.RemoveScheme(schemeName);
    _optionsCache.TryRemove(schemeName);
    await _ssoRepository.RemoveLoginsByLoginProviderAsync(schemeName);
  }

  public async Task UpsertAsync(string schemeName, string displayName, SsoConfig ssoConfig) {
    await Remove(schemeName);
    AddSaml2(schemeName, displayName, ssoConfig);
  }

  private void AddSaml2(string schemeName, string displayName, SsoConfig ssoConfig) {
    var scheme = new AuthenticationScheme(schemeName, displayName, typeof(Saml2Handler));
    CreateSamlOptions(schemeName, ssoConfig);
    _schemeProvider.TryAddScheme(scheme);
  }

  private void CreateSamlOptions(string schemeName, SsoConfig ssoConfig) {
    var o = new Saml2Options {
      SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme,
      SignOutScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme
    };

    // add it to the cache now, so that it gets found by the saml2handler...
    _optionsCache.TryAdd(schemeName, o);

    // Service provider options
    var myAppUrl = _coreSettings.Value.LinkApi;
    // SchemeName must be unique for each saml2 idp you add.
    // Note that schemeName here seems to need to not be able to include only numbers or dashes or the text "saml".
    // So just validate client side that it's only lowercase alphabetical letters only :shrug:.
    // Otherwise, they can't download the metadata xml file. It works though, otherwise.
    o.SPOptions.ModulePath = $"/saml2/{schemeName.ToLower()}";
    o.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId(myAppUrl);
    //o.SPOptions.WantAssertionsSigned = true;
    o.SPOptions.AuthenticateRequestSigningBehavior = Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.SigningBehavior.IfIdpWantAuthnRequestsSigned;
    o.SPOptions.ReturnUrl = new Uri(myAppUrl);

    // set where service provider metadata comes from
    string metaDataLocation = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ssoConfig.MetaDataXmlUrl)) {
      metaDataLocation = ssoConfig.MetaDataXmlUrl;
    } else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ssoConfig.MetaDataXml)) {
      // If they provide raw xml for their metadata, then we'll just get that from our db via this endpoint...
      metaDataLocation = new Uri(new Uri(myAppUrl), $"/api/sso/saml2metadata/{schemeName}").ToString();
    } else {
      throw new ValidationException("SAML2 SSO config must have either MetaDataXmlUrl or MetaDataXml set");
    }

    // helpful to look at source code: https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/master/Sustainsys.Saml2/IdentityProvider.cs
    IdentityProvider provider = null;
    try {
      provider = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId(ssoConfig.SamlEntityId), o.SPOptions) {
        MetadataLocation = metaDataLocation,
        LoadMetadata = true,
        // seems like HttpPost breaks unsolicitedauthnresponse from idp, so use Redirect instead? But wondering if that will break our signature part...guess we'll see
        //Binding = Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.Saml2BindingType.HttpPost,
        WantAuthnRequestsSigned = serviceProviderCertConfigured,
        AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,
      };

      if (provider.Binding == 0) throw new Exception($"SSO binding not set. Might have failed to write to {metaDataLocation}");

      o.IdentityProviders.Add(provider);
    } catch (XmlException ex) {
      throw new ValidationException($"Invalid SAML metadata XML: {ex.Message}");
    } catch (ConfigurationErrorsException ex) {
      throw new ValidationException($"Invalid SAML metadata XML: {ex.Message}");
    } catch (WebException ex) {
      throw new ValidationException($"Unable to retrieve SAML metadata XML: {ex.Message}");
    }
    /*
      Consider also handling these exceptions globally so you can show the user a nice error messages when they are configuring and testing their SSO:
      - ex is BadFormatSamlResponseException
      - ex is InvalidSignatureException
      - ex is NoSamlResponseFoundException
      - ex is Saml2Exception
      - ex is Saml2ResponseFailedValidationException
      - ex is UnexpectedInResponseToException
      - ex is UnsuccessfulSamlOperationException
      - ex is MetadataSerializationException
    */

    // set this, otherwise it errors with null reference due to the `Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.Saml2Urls` constructor not checking for null
    o.Notifications.GetPublicOrigin = _ => null;

    // sets logger. related: we might want/need to set o.CookieManager, otherwise they default to ChunkingCookieManager
    _samlPostConfigureOptions.PostConfigure(schemeName, o);
  }

  // Call this in a hosted service after your app starts up, handle errors nicely with retry logic and eventually notify slack or IT or something accordingly...
  // You may also want to hook an endpoint to it, so you can hit it manually if you need to rebuild all the sso configs for some reason without restarting your web server(s).
  public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> RebuildAllExistingSsoProvidersAsync(bool throwErrors) {
    // TODO: do each in parallel, if possible, so they don't block each other. But might not be possible since the saml library does a synchronous network request to get the metadata xml.
    
    // Get your SSO configs from your database...
    var identityProvidersInDb = await _ssoRepository.GetAllAsync();

    // Remove all registerd schemes and schemes that are in the db in case they got out of sync somehow
    // If an sso config was manually removed from the db, it will now be removed from the schemeProvider and optionsCache too.
    // If an sso config in the db was invalid, it may have still had its scheme added to the optionsCache, so that will be removed now.
    var existingSchemes = await _schemeProvider.GetAllSchemesAsync();
    var ssoSchemesInCache = existingSchemes.Where(s => s.HandlerType == typeof(Saml2Handler)).Select(s => s.Name);
    var ssoSchemesInDb = identityProvidersInDb.Select(p => p.SsoSchemeName);
    foreach (var ssoScheme in ssoSchemesInCache.Union(ssoSchemesInDb).Distinct()) await Remove(ssoScheme);

    // Add all the schemes back in, based on what's configured in the db
    var messages = new List<string>();
    foreach (var p in identityProvidersInDb) {
      try {
        AddSaml2(p.SsoSchemeName, p.SsoDisplayName, p.SsoConfig);
        messages.Add($"Successfully configured SSO for {p.SsoDisplayName}");
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        var errorMsg = $"Failed to configure SSO for {p.SsoDisplayName}. Fix the underlying error and then hit the sso controller endpoint to try adding all of them again /api/sso/startup: {ex}";
        if (throwErrors) throw new Exception(errorMsg);
        else messages.Add(errorMsg);
      }
    }
    return messages;
  }
}
```

SsoConfig.cs

```
public class SsoConfig {
  public string MetaDataXmlUrl { get; set; }
  public string MetaDataXml { get; set; }
  public string SamlEntityId { get; set; } // TODO: get from metadataxml...
}
```